# Aluminum to Copper run

Tags: copper, aluminum

I'm in the process of remodeling a bedroom in my house and will be replacing all the drywall. I'm contemplating the idea of replacing the aluminum wire in the room with copper. My question is can I replace the aluminum wire just in that room or does a run have to be all the same wire from the main to the end of the run. For example I was thinking I would find where the aluminum comes into the room and at that first outlet pigtail to copper wire, likely use AlumiConn, and use copper for the rest of the outlets. Same for he recessed lightning - replace from the switch up to the lights. Possible?

Answer (score 1):

Possible and definitely use AlumiConn and follow the [installation instructions](http://www.alcopstore.com/alumiconn-installation-instructions/). I got a torque screwdriver to pigtail my house (wiha 7.5 to 20 in.lb), but there are alternate instructions that don't specify torque.

You could just pigtail and not replace the aluminum conductor, but you would still want to pigtail the receptacles. The connections at the switches are reportedly less prone to failure, but I do those too and use the two-port Alumiconn connectors. I also use the 2-port on terminal receptacles.

When I am torquing an Alumiconn to 15 in.lb I find it helpful to put the connector in a Crescent wrench. It's easier and safer. I put the copper pigtails in ahead of time so I don't have to change the setting on the screwdriver while installing.

If I am approaching box fill, I use a twist on connector for the grounds, but I put on Penetrox A joint compound. Thirty years ago I pigtailed the receptacles and switches with twist on connectors and NoAlOx (an inferior antioxidant to Penetrox A) and I have had zero failures, but I am slowly going back and re-pigtailing with Alumiconn connectors. I think these are the only DIY connectors for connecting #12 or #10 aluminum to copper in branch circuits which are recommended by Jesse Aronstein http://www.kinginnovation.com/pdfs/alumiconn-docs.pdf